# How do I instantiate a javascript object from class reference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, constructor

I want to be able to instantiate objects in javascript (typescript) from a reference to the class. For instance, I want to be able to use some kind of factory function like so, but I don't know how to achieve this result.

```
class A {
    constructor() { this.b = 'somevalue'; }
}

const factory = (klass: Function) => {
    return new klass();
}

const instanceOfA = factory(A);
```

This example is rather contrived, but is there a way of doing this? The current error says `klass is not a constructor`. Alternatively if there's a more idiomatic way of instantiating things from a class reference, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Using the `new` operator is just the right way. Your only problem appears to be the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 6):

`Function` is just the wrong type, use a constructor type (which also helps infering the correct return type):

```
function factory<T>(klass: { new(): T }): T {
   return new klass();
}
```

Or as a `const` you assign to:

```
const factory = <T>(klass: { new(): T }) => {
    return new klass();
};
```